# Send POST request with string parameters to an URL using Windows.Web.HttpClient PostAsync()

Tags: c#, http, post, httpclient

I am able to send a POST request with string parameters to an URL using the `System.Web.HttpClient` like so:

```
// Create the HTTPClient
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

// Add string parameters
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "myclientid),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("serial_number", "myserialnumber)
});

// Make the call
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_requestUri, content);
```

However, I want to do the same, but with the `Windows.Web.HttpClient` class. 
The main difference is that the `PostAsync` method accepts an HttpContent as the second argument, so my `FormUrlEncodedContent` does not work. Also I cannot create an `IHttpContent` with JSON since I need to pass string parameters.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpformurlencodedcontent

I reckon all you need is to create a `HttpFormUrlEncodedContent` object instead and pass that in. It implements the `IHTTPContext` interface which is what your after